# When will Fairy Tail (2014) be dubbed?

Tags: fairy-tail

I really love the Fairy Tail anime, but cannot seem to find more dubbed episodes in English after episode 175. Does any one know when FUNimation will continue dubbing the Fairy Tail anime?

Comment: Funimation confirmed [here](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/convention/2013/sakura-con/10) that they will start releasing the dub for season 2 in july this year (2015). So I guess that would mean, this question should be reopened?

Comment: I tried to re-formulate your question, so if you think it differs from what you had intended to ask, please feel free to rollback any time.

Comment: @PeterRaeves well even then its still off-topic.

Comment: @Alagaros On what grounds? He is asking about an announced future event from a legal source. As far as I know, these are not off-topic.

Comment: @PeterRaeves hmm seems your right, my bad!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like my original comment does link to the release of season 2 of Fairy Tail, but a different season 2 as I assumed. It links to the release of Funimation's second Fairy Tail season aka episodes 49 to 72 and not to the 2014 sequel series aka all episodes going from 176.

I ended up saving face though as I eventually discovered that Funimation had actually announced their release date for their seventh season not too long ago. As you can see below, **[Fairy Tail season 7 (aka episodes 176 to 187) is scheduled for June 30th 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFlis.png)**.

The schedule can be found [here](http://www.funimation.com/schedule).

### Update

So the release should have been tomorrow, yet it seems the release has been delayed by six weeks. If you look at their current schedule, **Fairy Tail season 7 seems to be moved to August 11th 2015** as mentioned by [shadowx123](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/15350/shadowx123).

[image]